# Can an .awk file be executed with subprocess?

Tags: python, awk, subprocess

I have 3 files all within the same directory:

- ex.awk
- data.csv
- file.py

I want to execute my awk file using subprocess so I can call it within a PyTest testcase in the future. These are my sample files:

ex.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = ",";
}
{
    print NF;
}
END {print "DONE"}
```

data.csv

```
10,34,32
4,76,8304
4759,5869,2940
```

file.py

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['awk', '-f', 'ex.awk', 'data.csv']
subprocess.run(cmd)
```

On bash, the following command works:

```
$ awk -f ex.awk data.csv
3
3
3
DONE
```

I'm trying to get the same result when running file.py, but I get the following

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Am I missing some args in my array? Did I need to use some other subprocess args like `shell` or others?

Comment: In the shell where you run `file.py`, what happens if you try to run `awk`? Does that work? Fwiw, if I run `file.py` in a bash shell, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute the awk script from Python on Windows where you have encountered a `FileNotFoundError`, it's often due to the way Windows handles file paths or the execution of Unix/Linux-specific utilities that might not be directly available in the Windows command prompt environment. So you need to provide the absolute path or update Environment variable path to make it available.

Try these after adjusting the 'C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/awk.exe' path as necessary;

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/awk.exe', '-f', 'ex.awk', 'data.csv'] 
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
```

Alternatively, to execute it within a Unix-like shell provided by Git Bash or WSL:

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'awk -f ex.awk data.csv'
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, executable='C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe')
```

Comment: yep, exactly what I was saying: python can't find `awk` in the path.

Answer (score 1):

clearly, Python can't find the `awk` you specified in the `$PATH` (`%path%` on windows) environment variable it got executed with: your bash and your Python seem to see different lists of directories to look into to find executables!

So, you need to fix that – this looks like Windows, and I sadly can't tell you how to adjust environment variables on that niche operating system.

As a general remark: your `awk` script is not very good, and you should be careful about handling strings in the csv file containing `,` escaped or in quotes. And: Python does have a pretty capable `csv` module that can probably do what you're doing in `awk` rather easily. Seems a bit of an additional complication to add `awk` to the mix!

Comment: These were just some sample files to get a reproducible example. I am going to be going through hundreds of gigabytes of csv files and was told awk was the best for the job. Appreciate the help

Comment: @fuusei awk is not the optimal tool for parsing hundreds of gigabytes of CSV, certainly not :) (one question is who decided that gigabytes of numbers should be CSV, but that's a different problem…)

Comment: what would you consider to be the optimal tool for going through huge excel files with multiple regex expressions?

Comment: CSV is not an excel file. If you mean "csv" and not "excel", then probably `mlr` or just python's `csv` module and your own python code.

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work; the error seems to suggest a problem with your `PATH`.

However, your Awk script can trivially be reimplemented in Python.

```
import csv

with open("data.csv") as inp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    for row in reader:
        print(len(row))
# I would omit this
print("DONE")
```

Python's `csv` module is more sophisticated when it comes to handling of quoted fields, etc; if you require the more crude behavior of Awk, it's even simpler.

```
with open("data.csv") as inp:
    for row in inp:
        print(len(row.split(",")))
```

Awk and `sed` scripts make sense when called from the shell; they are very much part of the shell ecosystem. When you are writing Python, it almost always makes more sense to write the entire script in Python.